# MATLAB - Histogram Matching of Two Images

Tags: matlab, histogram, matching

I need to write a function which will match the histogram of `image2` to the image that will be remapped, let's call it `image1`. But I am not allowed to use `histeq`. Could you please help me with the code?

ps: Also I am wondering how would I do that operation if I were allowed to use `histeq`? What should I do after extracting red-green and blue channels? (I could not use `histeq(R2,R1)`?)

```
image1 = imread('color1.jpeg');
image2 = imread('color2.jpeg');

R1 = image1(:, :, 1);
G1 = image1(:, :, 2);
B1 = image1(:, :, 3);

R2 = image2(:, :, 1);
G2 = image2(:, :, 2);
B2 = image2(:, :, 3);
```

Regards,
Amadeus

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the question is specific enough. One way to solve this is to convert the three channels to a grayscale image (`rgb2gray`), compute the two histograms (`hist`) and then find a desired mapping between the histograms and apply it to each channel of the original image.

The conversion to grayscale is not necessary, you can perform this algorithm on each channel and then join the channels together later.

Check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6351377/histogram-matching-of-two-colored-images-in-matlab), which uses `histq`.

Comment: I did not understand what `HnRed1` is in his code. Which steps does he skip at the ... area?

Comment: Not sure, maybe `hist(Red1)`?

Comment: Check http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram_equalization, it explains what `histq` does.

Answer (score 0):

Histogram Matching algorithm consist of 3 stage:
1-compute Normalize CDF of first image(T(r)).
2-compute Normalize CDF of second image(G(z)).
3-calculate G^-1(T(r)) and transform intensity value of first image to desired one.